# Search a list for a range of numbers but return index of first example

Tags: python, list

> I have a list that I want to search for values from 500-535 in and I want to return the index for the first value found that is within that range.

```
mylist =[321, 344, 999, 512, 675, 555, 500]

rainday=forecastlist.index(range(500,531))

if not rainday:
    print("Empty")
```

> Obviously this isn't working.  I want it to return 3.  I don't want the location of the other values at this time, just the first one.

Comment: What if there is no such element?

Comment: I think that's what I was trying to do with the last two lines.  Haven't been able to test it yet.

Comment: Loop over each element and keep track of the index, if the first element meets you condition return index, otherwise return -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply construct a generator:

```
generator = (i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x in range(500,531))
```

you can then call it with:

```
first_index = next(generator)
```

If there is no such element, it will raise a `StopIteration` error. The nice thing about this solution is that you can call `next(..)` a second time, etc. to obtain all the indices:

```
>>> generator = (i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x in range(500,531))
>>> next(generator)
3
>>> next(generator)
6
>>> next(generator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

In your case you can thus write:

```
generator = (i for i,x in enumerate(mylist) if x in range(500,531))
first_index = next(generator)
try:
    rainday=next(generator)
except StopIteration:
    print("Empty")
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop over each element and keep track of the index, if the first element meets you condition return index, otherwise return -1

```
mylist =[321, 344, 999, 512, 675, 555, 500]

def check_ele_in_range(my_list, low, high):
    for ind, ele in enumerate(my_list):
        if low < ele < high:
            return ind
    return -1

print(check_ele_in_range(mylist, 500, 535))
print(check_ele_in_range([1,2,3], 500, 535))
```

Result:

```
3
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a simple function to return the first occurrence of an element inside of a given range. If a matching element is not found, `None` will be returned:

```
def first_occurrence(lst, range_):
    for pos, n in enumerate(lst):
        if n in range_:
            return pos
```

And you can use it like so:

```
first_match = first_occurrence(forecastlist, range(500,531))
if not first_match:
    print('empty')
```

However, if you don't want the behavior where an index of `0` fails the test condition, use `if first_match is None` instead of `if not first_match`.

Comment: `if not first_match` or  better `if first_match is None` since `0` can also trigger the first case

Comment: And you should return the index not the item

Comment: @MosesKoledoye While that is a valid point, I was simple going off of the OP's original code. Perhaps your right though and he doesn't that behavior.